# Formal justification of piecewise definition

Tags: functions

Let f be a function from A to C, and let g be a function from B to C, and suppose further f and g agree on the intersection of A and B. There exists a function h, namely the set-theoretic union of f and g, such that h(x)=f(x) if x is in A, and h(x)=g(x) if x is in B. My question is, is this the only function on A union B with this property? In other words, is there formal justification for defining functions piecewise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are defined to be equal if they agree on all inputs (and have the same domain and range).  If you prescribe the function's value on all elements of the domain, there can therefore be only one function that takes these values.

Answer (score 1):

It is the only function that meets the criteria. I don't understand what you mean by "formal justification".